# How to mutate columns in base r

Tags: r

I know how to do this in dplyr like so:

```
test <- df %>% mutate(col = ifelse(col == 0,NA,col)
```

How do I do this with base r?

Comment: `df$col[df$col==0] <- NA` or with assign to test `test <- df; test$col[test$col==0] <- NA`

Comment: `test <- within(df, col <- ifelse(col == 0, NA, col))` is probably the most syntactically similar method